# Integrating inverse trig function with radicals

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\dfrac{x + 5}{\sqrt{9-(x-3)^2}}$$

It's a inverse trig integration problem.

I tried to separate the numerators but made my problem worse.

Any advice?

Comment: Is it $x + \dfrac{5}{\sqrt{9-(x-3)^2}}$ or $\dfrac{x + 5}{\sqrt{9-(x-3)^2}}$? The site use MathJax (http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: The second one, thanks so much bro

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Please consider learning to post mathematical expressions using [MathJax](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and $\LaTeX$ if you will continue to participate.

Comment: According to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(x%2B5)%2Fsqrt(9-(x-3)%5E2)), this has to do with $\log$s, not inverse trig.

Comment: First let $x-3=3u$.

Comment: Why let x-3 = 3u?

Comment: This section is from the inverse trig function section, the trig sub method is still far ahead of me right now. Trying to solve this problem with u sub and inverse trig properties right now.

Comment: What is the purpose of letting it equal to 3u? I tried it but I don't see anything

Comment: $\sqrt{9-9u^2}=\sqrt{9} \sqrt{1-u^2}$

Comment: That looks good but then 3du = just dx?

Comment: yep and you will want to separate your fraction after sub too

Answer (score 0):

$$3u:=x-3\implies 3\,du=dx$$

and the integral becomes

$$\int\frac{3u+8}{\sqrt{9-9u^2}}3\,du=-\frac32\int\frac{-2u}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\,du+\frac83\int\frac1{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\,du$$

and now remember

$$\int\frac{f'}f dx=\log|f|\qquad(\arcsin x)'=\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$